# csrf disable is needed in securityFilterChain spring 6 but not in webSecurityConfigurationAdapter Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My Spring boot REST API application used to work fine with Spring 5 WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter even without disabling csrf. However, after upgrading to Spring 6 SecurityFilterChain I have to explicitly disable csrf for my POST endpoint to work...else I get a 403 forbidden invalid token from CsrfFilter. Does anyone know why? How did my POST work in Spring 5. Note: I am calling the https api deployed in a server from Postman.

Spring 5:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("cloudfoundryapplication"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint().excluding("health", "info")).authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

Spring 6:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: `How did my POST work in Spring 5?` how can we know when you havnt posted what your request looks like, your logs, or the endpoint you are calling